# Use AWS EBS instead of a redundant Database Server for backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, backup-strategies, aws-ebs

Iam new to AWS and iam tryin to find a good way for backing up my EC2 Instance.

I would like to run an application on my ec2 isntance with a database. Exactly, my application and also my database would run on the ec2 instance. My question is now whether it is useful at this point to use AWS EBS and to make snapshots of the instance storage for a backup or should I configure the database on a seperate instance with multi availability zones enabled ?

How to backup a ec2 instance in general?

do I have to use a redundant database on an external server? or is it possible to make snapshots and put them on ebs?

Comment: There are a number of problems with your question, including the fact that it's probably not on-topic for Stack Overflow.  The [DevOps Stack Exchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com) site is potentially more appropriate.  Additionally, you should never put anything important on the instance store volumes (they are ephemeral), and your database shouldn't be on the same instance as the application.

Comment: okay. I know that application and database should be seperate. But would this be a possible backup solution?

Comment: Are you really using [instance storage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html) or are you actually using EBS volumes?

Comment: i have tried both. In the instance menu i selected  32GB SSD instance storage and for a different instance i selected EBS only

Answer (score 1):

There are too many problem in your post, but I saw what you want are:

- Backup your application instance

- Backup your database

 If you use EC2 with EBS, it is not support multiAZ. AWS is already with many out-of-the-box functions, the easiest way is using very basic aws pattern:

- 1 EC2 instance for running your application. setup point-in-time snapshot backup. [This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html)

- 1 RDS with enabled multiAZ. Setup backup retention period (Default is daily). [This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html) 

If you calculate well, the pricing is not too much than you run instance with self manage.